# Android, using USB as storage to save photos

Tags: android, usb-drive

Is it possible to use USB pen drive as storage inside android applications?

Can it be connected to the mini usb port with some adapter or does it have to be Android Tablet that has USB 2.0 or USB 3.0 port available?

Comment: Yes. That ist posible if the device supports USB OTG. And if you do not use Kitkat or Lollipop as with them you can only read from sticks. Indeed that is not funny at all.

Comment: thank you. It will be deployed on one tablet only, so I can choose distribution